# Grep and use results in Bash Script

Tags: bash

Since I am new in Bash language, I was trying to make a simple script to find the apache2 PHP Config File (php.ini) in Ubuntu and echo a new line into it.

I have used the this code to find the currently used php.ini :

```
#!/bin/sh

php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"       && \
echo "zend_extension=/path/extension.so" > PHP.INI_GREPPED       && \
// The rest of my Code
```

So, Instead of the (PHP.INI_GREPPED) I want to use the found php.ini file in the previous command.

The output of (php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File) Shows this:

```
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

I want to only take (/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini) to echo a new line into it.

Also, IS it possible to change the file path before echo into it? for example, the output of the grep command was:

```
 Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

and I want to change the echo into :

```
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

NOTE: 7.4 may change depending on the installed version of PHP.

Anyway to do that? sorry I am new to bash.

Comment: You’re mixing sh and Bash. Pick one, they’re not the same.

Comment: @BHappy : Please indicate how you actually call your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html):

```
php -i | grep Loaded\ Configuration\ File | sed 's/.*=> //'
```

And without `grep`:

```
php -i | sed -n '/^Loaded Configuration File/s/.*=> //p'
```

Comment: Got you .. Thanks for that.. it works

Comment: can I make a variable with the path only? without php.ini ? to be like this: /etc/php/7.4/cli/

Comment: `p="$(php -i | grep Loaded\ Configuration\ File | sed 's/.*=> //')"`

Comment: The last command will make p as variable with the value (/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini). What I want is to make this variable: p = /etc/php/7.4/cli/ .. without php.ini

Comment: `d="$(dirname "$(php -i | grep Loaded\ Configuration\ File | sed 's/.*=> //')")"`

Comment: You should consider reading a [UNIX tutorial](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/).